# How to detect if user close Browser within Silverlight App

Tags: .net, silverlight, browser

How to detect if user close Browser within Silverlight App?

Can we grab it somehow so later save in database?

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs class, you can subscribe to the Exit event.

```
public partial class App : Application
{    
    public App()
    {
        this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Application Exiting");
    }
}
```