# Getting notified when user exits browser in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, browser

I have a Silverlight application where users can login. The problem is some users may not logout at all. I want to get notified in my application so that I can logout on his behalf. I have been browsing here and there but without any working solution. Most closely related article I found as this:  [How to notify an user when he tries to close a tab or close the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277717/how-to-notify-an-user-when-he-tries-to-close-a-tab-or-close-the-browser)  but could not get the result.

Can anybody point me, how can I be notified when user exit the application page or shutdown browser in my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109347/how-to-detect-if-user-close-browser-within-silverlight-app/28119621#28119621

Answer (score 0):

maybe a workaround with signal-R would work.

1. Create a Hub and override OnDisconnected
2. On start of your silverlight app or login - connect to the app

If users closes teh browser or tab, you will the OnDisconnected Method will be called.

Here are some more information:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/787033/SignalR-in-Silverlight

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#onreconnected

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Silverlight control in an [ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) page and you can call the Application [Unload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.unload.aspx) event override.

```
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped me to solve my problem

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private MainPage mainPage;
    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Log out the current user when application exits
        mainPage.LogoutCurrentUser();
    }
```